# Is there a more succinct way to get an ls -l type listing of the N biggest files with zsh?

Tags: zsh, glob

I puzzled out

```
$ for i in  **/*(.^oL[1,10]) ; ls -l $i 
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  82513 Jan  4 14:53 emoji/emoji-data.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  72009 Jan  4 14:53 glassfish/_asadmin
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  54528 Jan  4 14:53 gitfast/git-completion.bash
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  51886 Jan  4 14:53 chucknorris/fortunes/chucknorris
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  46593 Jan  4 14:53 emoji/emoji-char-definitions.zsh
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  36280 Jan  4 14:53 zsh-navigation-tools/LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  23433 Jan  4 14:53 pod/_pod
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  22757 Jan  4 14:53 history-substring-search/history-substring-search.zsh
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  15978 Jan 18 15:56 vault/_vault
-rw-r--r--  1 mscalora  staff  15268 Jan  4 14:53 scala/_scala
```

There must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` can take multiple arguments.

```
ls -lS **/*(.^oL[1,10])
```

Comment: but then they are not sorted in size order

Comment: In this case, you can let `ls` do the sorting with the `-S` option.

Comment: (Actually, I think you *have* to; `ls` does not appear to respect the order of its arguments when displaying its results.)

Comment: If you don't actually need `ls`, just some information about the displayed files, you can look at using `stat` instead. `stat -f "%n" *(-OL[1,10)` should display info in the order the files are listed by the glob. (`%n` is just the file name; other placeholders are available to construct a custom string for each file. Example shown is GNU `stat`; other versions vary.)